# how to Add multiple cmd shell command lines vb.net

Tags: vb.net, shell, adb

I want to run a few command lines by shell after I run the first command

I use the following command but it does not work

```
 Shell("cmd.exe /k" + "<adb shell 1> & <su 2> & <mv /data/local/tmp/build2.prop /system/build.prop 3>")
```

For example, I execute the following commands in cmd

adb shell

su

mv /data/local/tmp/build2.prop /system/build.prop

How can I run vb.net?

edite -----------------------------------------------------

Honestly, we need to transfer the file to vb.net into the Android device /system folder

We use [androidlib](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1512685) by the following command, but it does not work

```
Adb.ExecuteAdbCommand(Adb.FormAdbCommand("shell", "su", "-c", "mount -o remount, rw /system"))


Adb.ExecuteAdbCommand(Adb.FormAdbCommand("shell", "su", "-c", "cat /data/local/tmp/build2.prop > /system/build.prop"))
```

This command executes the read-only file system error

Comment: create a batch file and run that.

Comment: I do not want to create a .bat file. I want to include this in the software itself . Also, in the bat, when we enter the command "adb shell", "su" is not executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you appear to be after is executing additional commands ***inside*** `adb`, in which case what you're currently doing will not work. Combining commands with the ampersand `&` will execute each command ***separately***, not in a previously opened process.

To do what you want you've got to [**redirect standard input**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx) for the ***`adb` process***, not CMD.

Redirecting the input is simply a way of changing where the process gets its input from. Instead of getting it from the keyboard input stream (the user) you can redirect it to a different stream which you have control over.

Untested, but something like this should work:

```vb
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("adb", "shell 1")
psi.UseShellExecute = False
psi.RedirectStandardInput = True

Dim p As Process = Process.Start(psi)
Dim InputStream As StreamWriter = psi.StandardInput

InputStream.WriteLine("su 2")
InputStream.WriteLine("mv /data/local/tmp/build2.prop /system/build.prop 3")
```

Comment: Thank you  But after executing adb shell, it does not execute the next code

Comment: @ILYA20 : Are the other parts really commands, or are they just what you want to send to the `adb shell`?

Comment: I think your command is okay
Even I created a .bat file and placed the commands in this file
But it does not execute commands after the adb shell, and it only stays in the adb shell
This is an adb.exe property.

Comment: @ILYA20 : Well if that's the case then you're doing it wrong. `&` is used to execute multiple _**separate**_ commands. If you want to pass them along to `adb` you've either got to redirect the input or pass them as parameters.

Comment: @ILYA20 : Updated my answer.